# C# Distinguish between first and second match

Tags: c#, regex

I am using regex to extract the numbers from a string which contains a range. The range could be `"less than x"`, `"greater than x"` or `"between x and y"`:

```
"10 - 22"
"< 0,5"
"3.50000 - 11.0"
"< 120000"  
"> 12"
```

Below is the relevant code snippet. In the case of `"less than x"` and `"greater than x"` I use the RegEx `(\d*,\d*)?(\d*)` to capture the integer/decimal.

```
Low = r.Descr.Contains('>') 
    ? new Quantity {
        Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Regex.Match(r.Descr, @"(\d*,\d*)?(\d*)").Value)
    } 
    : r.Descr.Contains('-') 
    ? new Quantity {
        Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Regex.Match(r.Descr, @"").Value) 
    } 
    : null,
High = r.Descr.Contains('<') 
    ? new Quantity {
        Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Regex.Match(r.Descr, @"(\d*,\d*)?(\d*)").Value) 
    }
    : r.Descr.Contains('-') 
    ? new Quantity { 
        Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Regex.Match(r.Descr, @"").Value) 
    } 
    : null,
```

In the case of `"between x and y"` I am having difficulties in constructing a RegEx which would extract the relevant number. Is there a way to do this using RegEx for the three patterns?

Comment: what does 3,50000 - 11,0 mean

Comment: It is `var m = Regex.Match(text, @"(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*-\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)*)");`, then you will be able to get the numbers from `m.Groups[1].Value` and `m.Groups[2].Value`.

Comment: @GoldenLion that would be between 3.5 and 11.0.

Comment: The Contains part checks for a char < or >, but the pattern `(\d*,\d*)?(\d*)` could also match an emtpy string or only a comma. Using `\d+(?:,\d+)?` you will match at least a single digit.

Comment: the data needs edited above too reflect 3.5 - 11.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*-\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)*)");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%2B%29%3F%29%5Cs*-%5Cs*%28%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%2B%29*%29&i=some%20words....3%2C50000%20-%2011%2C0%20....%20text....). *Details*:

- `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits followed with an optional occurrence of a comma and one or more digits
- `\s*-\s*` - a `-` enclosed with zero or more whitespace chars
- `(\d+(?:,\d+)*)` - Capturing group 2: one or more digits followed with an optional occurrence of a comma and one or more digits

Now, `match` contains a `3,50000 - 11,0` substring in Group 0, and the rest two groups contain your values:

```cs
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - first number", match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - second number", match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/EL8xFQ):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "some words....3,50000 - 11,0 .... text....";
        var match = Regex.Match(text, @"(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*-\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)*)");
 
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - first number", match.Groups[1].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - second number", match.Groups[2].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3,50000 - first number
11,0 - second number
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this expression:

```
(\d+,?\d+\s*-\s*\d+,?\d+)|(<\s*\d+,?\d+)|(>\s*\d+,?\d+)
```

This expression contains three individual expressions separated by a pipe character (`|`). The pipe character means "or".

- The first expression `(\d+,?\d+\s*-\s*\d+,?\d+)` matches every number decimal or not that is separated by `-`.
- The second part `(<\s*\d+,?\d+)` matches less than x expression, and
- The third part `(>\s*\d+,?\d+)` matches the greater than x expression.

So the global expression extracts the between case, the less than than case, or the greater than case. As such, it seems to meet all of the cases searched.